Upload Image Complains of Missing URL
I am trying to set up a mailmerge template that contains a couple of logos.
If I create it in Word first, I can't persuade Civi to merge any of the tokens.
If I create it on screen, I can insert tokens, but I can't insert images.
When I try to upload an image, I get "Image source URL is missing".
I have no idea what this is referring to. The source is the image that I am uploading.
Any clues? Even better, how can I insert tokens in the Word document and just import that?

Update: the contact ID will merge correctly, but none of the other fields will.
